# Fixed MKAnnotation size

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

In my iOS app (swift 4) I want to have circle annotations (custom image) of a specific size, but I cannot find anywhere that explains how to fix the size/scale of an annotation regardless of map zoom.

When I zoom out I want them to all be small so you can view a large area without it being too cluttered, but when I zoom in close I don't want them to shrink and reveal the centre of the circle, as they currently do.

Is there any way to define the size of a custom annotation image?

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: I think managing size of your annotation image can do the trick.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Tried that, image still grows and shrinks with the zoom level

Comment: I think you can find workaround for this problem below.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286711/resize-mkannotationview-image-when-map-zooms-in-and-out)

Comment: followed all steps but still was not scaling properly... @AbuUlHassan

Answer (score 1):

You can scale it if needed inside `viewForAnnotation`

```
annotationView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)        
return annotationView
```

Comment: annotation still scales with zoom... would some screenshots help?

Comment: @LiamOttley have you found the solution to your problem yet? I'm in the process of applying scalable `MKAnnotations` dependant of of the actual `mapVIew`zoom but all the posts I found on this topic, including the suggested in the link, are way old and with a syntax that I barely understand, let alone update to swift 4. Could you please share your code even if you haven't found the solution yet so that other not experienced learning programmers, as myself, can benefit and learn from it? Many thanks