# Resizing MKAnnotationView as user zooms in and out

Tags: swift, uiview, mapkit, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I am trying to resize my custom `MKAnnotationView` as the user scrolls in and out of the map similar to how the `MKMarkerAnnotationView` behaves.
Currently when the user scrolls in and out of the map my custom annotation stays the same size instead of getting smaller when the user zooms out and larger when the user zooms in.
I have tried using this example  [Outdated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286711/resize-mkannotationview-image-when-map-zooms-in-and-out) however the code seems to be a bit outdated and when I tried the extension suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46072791/9367155) the behavior is not always as expected the view tends to shift a bit around the map and when the user scrolls in and out very fast the behavior is a bit strange.

Below is my raw implementation of the `mapViewDelegate` based loosely off of the apple project mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_annotations/annotating_a_map_with_custom_data).

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {


        if annotation is MKUserLocation{
            return nil
        }else if let cluster = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation{
            let view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier, for: cluster) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView

            view?.annotation = cluster
            view?.markerTintColor = UIColor.green


            return view
        }
        else if let marker = annotation as? ReusableAnnotation{
            let view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier, for: marker)
            view.annotation = marker
            view.clusteringIdentifier = "cluster"

            view.canShowCallout = true
//            view.detailCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "apolloRocket"))

//            view.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "apolloRocket").resizeImage(150, opaque: false) // #imageLiteral(resourceName: "apolloRocket")
            let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
            subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            view.addSubview(subView)

            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
            return view
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Thank you for all of your help in advance.

Comment: What you want is an overlay rather than an annotation.

Comment: @matt Thank you for always helping I truly appreciate your advise. Would it be possible to put a subview inside of the overlay such as an UIImageView or UILabel? I’ve read on some of the other questions that overlays can be memory or CPU intensive, is any merit to that claim?

Comment: It's a view, it's like any view.